# How to Declare Nib file?

Tags: iphone

How to declare nib file with initwithnib syntax It display `'Warning: passing argument 1 of initwithNibName:bundle: from Incompatible pointer type'`.

my statement is:

```
SpanishViewController *spanishview = [[SpanishViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:"LocalizeMeViewController.xib (es)" 
             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Thanks in Advance........

Comment: its string type @"yourNibName"

Comment: use a compatible pointer type. Without showing some code this is all I can tell.

Comment: use this initWithNibName:@"LocalizeMeViewController" bundle:nil

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really know what you're doing with custom NIB filenames, you should be loading NIBs like this:

```
self.myViewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

or:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Apple is liable to add some new feature in the future, unannounced, that depends upon this "I don't care, choose the NIB automatically, please" feature.

PS: "incompatible pointer type" means you tried to pass it a variable of the wrong "type". You probably wrote:

```
[... initWithNibName:"name" bundle:nil]
```

... i.e. forgot the "@" symbol. That turns it into a different type/pointer type to what is expected (a particular kind of string pointer).

---

EDIT: now that you've added your actual code, I suspect you're doing localization the wrong way. Check the Apple docs, but off the top of my head, you provide multiple copies of the same NIB with *identical* name, but stored in different sub-directories, one per language.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not putting the exact name of your xib. I wouldn't recommend putting parentheses on a Nib name. And as Adam said, you need to put a '@' before it, since it is still a NSString it gets as a parameter. So the name should be a NSString. @"myNibName"

Comment: would be nice if that would trigger a warning. But unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: No, "incompatible pointer type" means he probably wrote: initWithNibName:"name" bundle:nil ... i.e. he forget the "@" symbol. That turns it into a different type ("pointer type") to what is expected (string pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
SpanishViewController *spanishview = [[SpanishViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"LocalizeMeViewController" 
         bundle:nil];
```

Comment: No, that will never work. Try it in Xcode - you are passing an incorrect type (strings in obj-C need to be built by hand, passed by appropriate pointer ref ... unless you use the special magical @ syntax :)